# Why doesn't my if...in statement work in python?

Tags: python, arrays

this program takes 3 lists of numbers, and compares A and B to the list n. if a term from A is in n, the happiness increases. if a term from B is in n, the happiness decreases. However, when I am doing these calculations, the if ... in statement to check if a term from A/B is in n doesn't work - I have done print(happy) after each one to check, and I get no result

```
A = []
B = []
n = []
happy = 0
lengthn, lengthAB = input("").split()
for i in lengthn:
    numbers = input("")
newNumbers = numbers.split()
n.append(newNumbers)
for i in lengthAB:
    numbers = input("")
ANumbers = numbers.split()
A.append(ANumbers)
for i in lengthAB:
    numbers = input("")
BNumbers = numbers.split()
B.append(BNumbers)

long = int(lengthAB)
for i in range(long):
    j = int(i)
    if A[j - 1] in n:
        happy = happy + 1
        print(happy)
    if B[j - 1] in n:
        happy = happy - 1
        print(happy)
    i = i + 1

print(happy)
```

Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: Is the indentation correct? Should `n.append(newNumbers)` be in the loop above? Also, I 'think this should be `extend`, not `append`, and numbers should be mapped to `int` first. Same for the following two loops.

Comment: `for i in lengthn:` when `lengthn` seems to be a string?

Comment: I would recommend split this code into a couple function. Separate calculations from IO operations. Then show example of function input and expected returned value.

Answer (score 0):

You appended a *list* to `n`, not each element of that list. You can write

```
n.extend(newNumbers)
```

instead.

You *could* just write `n = newNumbers.split()`, but as pointed out in a comment, you probably have an indentation error:

```
for i in lengthn:
    numbers = input("")
    newNumbers = numbers.split()
    n.extend(newNumbers)
```

Or, you don't need split at all:

```
for i in lengthn:
    number = int(input(""))
    n.append(number)
```

At some point, you probably mean to convert the string inputs to integers; may as well do that immediately after reading the string. (I'm declaring various techniques for handling conversion errors beyond the scope of this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what you seem to expect the variables: `lengthn, lengthAB` are strings

The **for**-loop

```
for i in lengthn:
    numbers = input("")
```

iterates over the characters in the string lengthn. If `lengthn='12'` it will ask to provide input twice.

If lengthAB is '13' for example you will get 2 numbers in your list BNumbers but later on you try to test 13 values because int('13') is 13.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for i in lengthn:
     numbers = input("")
```

so the numbers you are getting are the form of string it's will iterate on string rather then a number.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for beeter python book. Based on desription I think this should look like this:

```py
def happiness(A, B, n):
    return sum(x in n for x in A) - sum(x in n for x in B)

def get_data(prompt=""):
    return [int(x) for x in input(prompt).split()]

print(happiness(get_data(), get_data(), get_data()))
```

https://ideone.com/Q2MZCo